# MySQL error "no such directory or file"

Tags: php, mysql

I continue to receive an SQL error "no such directory or file" on `mysql_query` after selecting data from my database.

```
<?php

require_once ('config.php');
session_start();
$select_db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);
if ($select_db) {
    die("no db" . mysql_error());
}

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($config, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($config, $_POST['password']);

    $query = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";


    $result = mysql_query($config, $query)or die("unable to find data " . mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if ($count == 1) {
        $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
        header('location: home.html');
    } else {
        echo "invalid credentials";
    }
}
?>
```

The error occurs on the following line (also shown above):

```
$result=mysql_query($config, $query) or die("unable to find data ".mysql_error());
```

Does anyone know why I get the "no such directory or file" SQL error?

Comment: Where does the value ``$config`` come from? Is it set anywhere?

Comment: mysql_query is deprecated. Use PDO or mysqli_query instead.

Comment: I also got that error once for quite a while (a few hours). Restarting mysql did the job.

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** mysql_* functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements.

Comment: echo the query and run it on mysql sql dialog directly and see of you get any db errors

Comment: can you share the contents of the config.php file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U are trying to mixup mysqli (latest,must use) and old mysql(deprecated) . u are using $config as if it's a mysqli. first recreate your code because even if somehow it worked, cheers for no longer.

u can find functions for mysqli here

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php